# User credentials cannot be used for local connections for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, servicenow

I have been playing around with PowerShell for the last week using ServiceNow. I keep receiving this error message "User credentials cannot be used for local connections". I have searched all of the Internet for a reason behind this and I a lost.

The script I am trying to run is the following:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Share" -Members "tuser1" -confirm:$false -credential user
```

When I run this locally on the machine it works fine, but ServiceNow downloads the script and runs it.

I have tried to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -force`

Comment: Why are you specifying the -Credential parameter?

Comment: Yes the I have a user stored in the ServiceNow credential table. \

Comment: The -Credential parameter requires a PSCredential object. The `Password` property of a PSCredential object is a `SecureString` object. I'm not sure exactly what you're expecting to work.